# Advanced Lookup required

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, max, vlookup

I'm in need of some advanced lookup formula with MAX, MIN, IF and SUM. Info:

```
Sheet1 (data):
Column one(A): name
Column two (B): Type
Column three (D1:AO): Data/numbers
```

Row 1: A1=Name, B1= Type, D1:AO1=name of the different data

```
Sheet2 (output):
B5: Primary Critera, Selecting from a dropdownlist of Sheet1.Row(D1:AO1)
B7: Secondary Critera, Selecting from a dropdownlist of Sheet1.Row(D1:AO1)
B8: Tertiary Critera, Selecting from a dropdownlist of Sheet1.Row(D1:AO1)
B9: Quaternary Critera, Selecting from a dropdownlist of Sheet1.Row(D1:AO1)
B10: Quinary Critera, Selecting from a dropdownlist of Sheet1.Row(D1:AO1)
```

What I want:

**Step 1:**
I want it to find the row in sheet1(D1:AO1) that matches Sheet2(B5), and find the Maximum value in that column and paste the name Sheet1(Column one).

**Step 2 (Maximum criteria):**
There are five different types Sheet1(Column two). I want it to find Step 1 for each of them (so five Maximum value, pasting the name in five different cells).

**Step 3 (Minimum criteria):**
Sheet2(B7:B10) are four minimum criteria (such as =<10), which also needs to be taken into consideration (unless its "None"). Like step one these four cells are dropdown lists.

**Step 4 (Total):**
Sum up the values of each of the criteria in different cells.

**Example:**
Type 1-5: Books, Cd's, DVD's, Clothes, Shoes - 100 different of each Type

B5: Primary Criterion: Selling Price
B7: Secondary Criterion: Market value =< 10

Then I want it to find the highest selling price (Primary Criterion), with a minimum market value of `10`, for each Type 1-5. Also, pasting the sum of selling price (five prices in total), and pasting the sum of market value (five values in total).

This is how I tried to start step 1:

```
If(B5="None";"";MAX(VLOOKUP(B5='Sheet1!'!D1:AO1
```

But, I got stuck since it's lookup in sheet1.cells(D1:AO1), and pasting is column one.

Also, it would even be a great help if you could just solve one of the steps.

**EDIT - STEP 1:**
A formula that says
1) Look for a cell in Sheet1.row1, where the text matches the text in Sheet2(B5).
2) If you find one, Search the specific column with the match, for the maximum value.
3) return/paste the text from column A, of which row of the maximum value.

[image: SO28460606 question example]

Comment: Yeah sorry for the unclear post. Read at the bottom EDIT - STEP1.   Unfortunately I am not allowed to post picture yet, but you can find a picture from following link:  
http://s13.postimg.org/d6n6alomf/Sk_rmbillede_2015_02_11_kl_20_55_44.png

Orange = Match/search value  
Blue = Max value in the column of the Match/search result
Green = the text to be copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B9 please try:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(OFFSET(A:A,,MATCH(B7,1:1,0)-1)),OFFSET(A:A,,MATCH(B7,1:1,0)-1),0))
```